# How to inline style child DOM element React?

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles, radium

Let imagine I import library react-select or any other that I don't have direct access to its component and jsx. Is it possible to pass your own style to child DOM element like drop down menus from other library. Like your can with normal css `div div div{... here you will style only children}`. I am using Radium.

In my case I want to change the z-index of Select Select--single is-searchable class and style drop down menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radium provide so called Style component that allows you to style such components that you imported from other libraries Link: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/tree/master/docs/api#style-component.

Example:

```
<Style
  scopeSelector=".scoping-class"
  rules={{
    color: 'blue',
    span: {
      fontFamily: 'Lucida Console, Monaco, monospace'
    }
  }}
/>
```